# Why robots.txt still not blocking urls I have mentained

Tags: robots.txt

Its been 48 hours since I updated my robots.txt file you can have a look at my robots.txt file here:-

```
https://www.qapaper.com/robots.txt
```

I disallowed url's that are like

```
/SRM-abc+nksf
/SRM-anything+here
```

That's why I have mentained

```
Disallow:/SRM-
```

But I like to have url's like

```
/SRM-inc/joid-lkn
```

That's why I have mentained

```
/SRM-*/
```

I have checked with **robots.txt** tester it is giving me desired test but isn't removing my url's from google search results.
Have a look:

```
site:qapaper.com
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that waiting 48 hours would be enough?